# My js code won't work on IE10

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-10

Here's my JS code..

```
 <script>
var sticky = document.querySelector('.sticky');
var origOffsetY = sticky.offsetTop;

function onScroll(e) {
window.scrollY >= origOffsetY ? sticky.classList.add('fixed') :
                              sticky.classList.remove('fixed');
}

document.addEventListener('scroll', onScroll);

</script>
```

It's used to let a div stays in place even when the user scrolls down.

It doesn't work in IE10 (which has `querySelector`, `classList`, and `addEventListener`, so it's not that).

Comment: How does it "not work"? What errors do you see in the IE10 dev tools?

Comment: not working? failed gracefully without errors?

Comment: It didn't work because the function it's supposed to do won't work... When I try to browse the website with Firefox... the div will stay fixed but when it's on IE ..... it just won't work

Comment: I love it how you have not 1 single accepted question out of your 6, regardless can you reproduce the problem in a fiddle ?

Comment: @ShericaFabienneOcbania: Again: What do you see in the dev tools console?

Comment: It's not even returning any errors. I'll create a fiddle for this wait

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IE10 doesn't support `scrollY`. You have to use `scrollTop` on `document.documentElement`:

```
var sticky = document.querySelector('.sticky');
var origOffsetY = sticky.offsetTop;
var hasScrollY = 'scrollY' in window;

function onScroll(e) {
  var y = hasScrollY ? window.scrollY : document.documentElement.scrollTop;
  y >= origOffsetY ? sticky.classList.add('fixed') : sticky.classList.remove('fixed');
}

document.addEventListener('scroll', onScroll);
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/isOMavU/1) | [Live Source](http://jsbin.com/isOMavU/1/edit)

*(You may not need the check, it's possible all of your target browsers support `document.documentElement.scrollTop` and you could just always use that.)*

Comment: How I got there: Basic debugging. Since it's hard to walk through code for scroll event handlers, I just logged relevant things until I found that `window.scrollY` was always `undefined` on IE10.